# Privacy tab using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, applescript-objc, nsapplescript, applescript-studio

I am trying to access the *Privacy* -> *Accessibility* tab using Applescript. Can anyone help me?

I need to display a list of all the programs in the section:

- Accessibility
- Camera
- Microphone
- Photos
- etc...

The request itself and the output in the terminal using `osascript -e`.

It is necessary to exclude interaction with the GUI. Here's what I managed to find

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the name of every login item'
```

I need to find the same solution for *Accessibility*? And get the result the same as in the screenshot below.

The main goals are

1. Locally get the information contained in *Security & Privacy*
   2)Connect to mac OS via SSH and get the information contained in *Security & Privacy*. If this is not possible, then how to display the information using a single Apple script.

Comment: In order to get the information your want without using **UI Scripting**, then you'll need to query the **TCC.db** database using `sqlite3`.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what he would give me
Library/Application Support/com.apple.EU/EU.vi ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is necessary to exclude interaction with the GUI (on the *remote system*).

Testing with the *remote system* being **macOS Big Sur** 11.6 and having checked **[√] Allow full disk access for remote users** in **System Preferences** > **Sharing** > **Remote Login** on the *remote system*, then the *example* **shell script** *code* executed in **Terminal** on the *local system* in a `ssh` *session* to the *remote system* will give you a *raw* dump of what's listed under **Accessibility** in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** without the need for **UI Scripting** with **AppleScript**.

```zsh
sqlite3 '/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db' 'SELECT client FROM access WHERE service="kTCCServiceAccessibility";'
```

On the test system its *output* was:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/Support/AEServer
com.apple.AccessibilityInspector
com.apple.Automator
com.apple.ScriptEditor2
com.apple.Terminal
com.latenightsw.ScriptDebugger8
```

If you really have a need to use **AppleScript** you could, however, say you needed the *output* to be pretty. In other words, using an **AppleScript** *script* saved as a *shell script* using a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` *shebang* the *output* on the same *remote system* would be e.g.:

```
AEServer, Accessibility Inspector, Automator, Script Editor, Terminal, Script Debugger
```

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/osascript

set theAccessibilityList to paragraphs of (do shell script "sqlite3 '/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db' 'SELECT client FROM access WHERE service=\"kTCCServiceAccessibility\";'")

set theAccessibilityApplicationNamesList to {}
repeat with thisItem in theAccessibilityList
    if thisItem starts with "/" then
        set shellCommand to (do shell script "f=" & quoted form of thisItem & "; echo ${f##*/}")
        set end of theAccessibilityApplicationNamesList to shellCommand
    else
        try
            set end of theAccessibilityApplicationNamesList to the name of application id thisItem
        end try
    end if
end repeat

return theAccessibilityApplicationNamesList
```

**Notes:**

I created, saved and made executable the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, on the *local system* and then copied it the from the *local system* to the *remote system* using `scp`.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Your answer suits me, but for some reason nothing works for me. I get empty values what could be the problem?

Comment: @Georgy, RE: "Your answer suits me, but for some reason nothing works for me. I get empty values what could be the problem?" --  **Please reread my answer.** --- The _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ shown in my answer **is not intended** to be used in **Script Editor** as in the screen shot you just added to your question.  It is meant be be used  in **Terminal** as a _shell script_, made executable and copied to the _remote system_ using `scp` and then executed in a `ssh` _session_.

Comment: I understand thanks for the answer. But if I'm interested in running two scenarios? How do I do it on a local machine using a Terminal?

Comment: @Georgy, RE: "I understand thanks for the answer. But if I'm interested in running two scenarios? How do I do it on a local machine using a Terminal?" --  In your question you state "The main goal is to connect to mac OS via SSH" you did not say anything about doing it locally! You also modified the _path_ to the **TCC.db** _database_ in my _code_! My answer works as stated under the conditions stated! The next time you post a question I'd strongly urge you to include everything you need and not keep changing the parameters as people try to help you.

Comment: @Georgy, RE: "I checked the empty values remotely too, nothing works." --  If you run the _code_ as I've written it without editing the _path_ to the **TCC.db** _database_ it should work, providing the other conditions are met. The entries for **Accessibility** are not stored in `~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db` and why it returns nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer you helped me a lot

Comment: How do I view other values ?
Full access to disk, Files and folders?

Comment: @Georgy, Just an FYI... Depending one what one is targeting, some information is in the **TCC.db** _database_ in the `$HOME` _directory_. as an example to get the _applications_ approved to use the **Camera** it would be locally e.g.: `sqlite3 "$HOME/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db" 'SELECT client FROM access WHERE service="kTCCServiceCamera";'`

Comment: @Georgy, RE: "How do I view other values ? Full access to disk, Files and folders?" --  Use the proper search query on the proper _database_. I do not have a _list_ handy, however I'm sure googling for it should turn up something.

Comment: @Georgy, Have a look at [macOS TCC.db Internals](https://rainforest.engineering/2021-02-09-macos-tcc/) and remember some are in `'/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db'` and others in `"$HOME/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db` so you you can either query both or figure our which are in which when you expand the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ to accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the nested quotes following way. And, activate the System Preferences.

```
osascript -e "
tell application id \"com.apple.systempreferences\"
activate
reveal anchor named \"Privacy_Accessibility\" in pane id \"com.apple.preference.security\"
end tell
tell application id \"sevs\" to tell process \"System Preferences\"
repeat until window \"Security & Privacy\" exists
delay 0.02
end repeat
tell scroll area 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window \"Security & Privacy\"
get value of static text 1 of UI element 1 of rows of table 1
end tell
end tell"
```

Or, if needed table view (on right) of needed item (on left) is already opened, you can use following osascript on the Catalina:

```
osascript -e "
tell application id \"sevs\" to tell process \"System Preferences\"
set frontmost to true
tell scroll area 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window \"Security & Privacy\" to get value of static text 1 of UI element 1 of rows of table 1
end tell"
```

Comment: Not exactly what you need. I managed to find osascript -e "inform the application "SYSTEM events" to get the value of the static text of 1 user interface element 1 table rows 1 scroll area 1 group 1 tab group 1 window 1 application process "System Settings" " Information output suits me, but it does not work without an active window. It is necessary without using a graphical interface.

Comment: I updated the answer. I am on the Catalina, so GUI scripting code lines is written for it

Comment: You would not have to waste time escaping _double-quotes_ with a _backslash_ if you used _single-quotes_ for the opening and closing of the _statements_, where `...` are the remaining unescaped _double-quotes_ in _statements_ in e.g.: `osascript -e 'tell application id "com.apple.systempreferences" ...'`

Comment: No, all these decisions are wrong, there is interaction with the graphical interface. It is necessary to exclude interaction with the GUI.  Here's what I managed to find osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the name of every login item' . I need to find the same solution for Accessibility?

Comment: user3439894 what did you mean by double-quotes with a backslash if you used single-quotes for the opening and closing of the statements. If there is a suggestion, then listen carefully?

Comment: @Georgy, RE: "what did you mean by double-quotes with a backslash if you used single-quotes for the opening and closing of the statements." -- In the _code_ of this answer all the _double-quotes_ within the opening/closing _double-quotes_ are escaped with a `backslash` and if the _code_ was written using _single-quotes_ for the opening/closing of the _statements_ then one would not have to waste time escaping _double-quotes_ with a _backslash_ and would not be necessary as in the example snippet of _code_ show in my first comment.

Comment: @Georgy, RE: "If there is a suggestion, then listen carefully?"  I have no idea what you are trying to say here.

Comment: is it supposed to work for me big sur?

Comment: @Georgy, RE: "No, all these decisions are wrong, there is interaction with the graphical interface. It is necessary to exclude interaction with the GUI. Here's what I managed to find osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get the name of every login item' . I need to find the same solution for Accessibility" -- Well you do not qualify that in your OP and if that's what you need then edit your question to include what you needs are!  That said, you can not use **System Events** with **Accessibility** in the same way as with `login items`, it just doesn't work that way.

Comment: I have updated and specified the main goal